# read text from file C string terminator

Tags: c, file-io, char

I want to read a text from file which contains also '\n' character

This is my function

```
void readFromFile (FILE * fid, unsigned char * mesage) {
    unsigned char c;
    int mesage_length = 0;

    while((c = fgetc(fid)) != EOF) {
        mesage[mesage_length] = c;
        mesage_length++;
    }
}
```

I have completely absolute no idea why when it gets to the '\n' my program crashes, it enters in an infinite loop and the mesage_length grows up to 13992 or something, but i read only 13 characters like : "Why not working?\n"

How can i read the whole text until `EOF` and put it into a string (char *) ?

If i put the condition inside the while `if(c == '\n') break;` it works fine.. but would read until the first `\n`

Comment: Where have you allocated `mesage`, how large is it?

Comment: Declare c as `int`. This is the type returned by `fgetc` and of  `EOF`.

Comment: how are you terminating that string as well? unless you've initialized `mesage` to be all-nulls, you'll just have whatever random garbage was in that chunk of memory, and printing out the string would just keep printing trash until you per-chance hit a null char.

Comment: what Eugene says, `EOF` is usually -1, you declare `c` as unsigned char. Didn't your compiler complain?